# Using jquery countdown timer with mysql datetime?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I know this question has been asked many times as I have found a few on google and also on stackoverflow.

but none of them explained how to format my datetime in my php so it works in combination with jquery countdown timer. so I am going to ask it here in a hope i get someone shed a light on this for me.

Basically what i am trying to do is to create a countdown timer which will work with mysql datetime.

the datetime is stored in mysql so All need to do is to get the correct format in my php so the countdown timer could work with it.

I am using this plugin: http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

and here is what i have so far:

PHP formatting:

```
$end_date = date("m d Y H:i:s T", strtotime($row["end_date"]));
```

Jquery/Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
    var countdown = $('#countdown'),
        ts = new Date(<?php echo $end_date * 1000; ?>),
        finished = true;

    if((new Date()) > ts)
    {
        finished = false;
    }

    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({
        timestamp   : ts,
        callback    : function(days, hours, minutes, seconds)
        {
            var message = "";

            message += days + " days, ";
            message += hours + " hours, ";
            message += minutes + " minutes, ";
            message += seconds + " seconds ";

            message = (finished ? "Countdown finished" : "left untill the New Year");

            countdown.html(message);
        }
    });

});

</script>
```

when i run this code, all i get is `0 hours, 0 minutes, 0 seconds.`

I can only suspect that the issue is from formatting the datetime in my php section!

or am i missing something else as well?

**okay I have managed to minify the code to this:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({
        until: new Date(<?php echo $end_date; ?>),
        compact: true
    });
});

</script>
```

and changed the php to this:

```
$end_date = date("Y, n, j, G, i, s", strtotime($row["end_date"]));
```

However, the time shown in the coutdown timer is wrong (way off).

the `$end_date` is: `September 22 2013 23:30:00 GMT` in mysql datetime

but the jquery countdown timer is showing:

```
34d 06:21:48
2013, 9, 22, 23, 30, 00
```

34days and 6 hours blah blah is absolutely wrong!

what am i doing wrong here now?

Comment: Why are you multiplying `$end_date` by 1000?

Comment: @MartyMcVry, not sure why but i thought i might as well try that as nothing was working!

Comment: Remove it :-) Are you sure the row is fetched correctly?

Comment: @MartyMcVry, I have removed it. please view my edited question.

Comment: The countdown timer gets the right data... Is your computer set to the correct date?

Comment: @MartyMcVry, The Computer?! I think you are missing the point mate. the countdown timer gets the data from mysql. its not client side. its server side.

Comment: Erm... It's a JavaScript timer, that's **client** side. The server side seems to work: the timer gets the data that's in the MySQL db...

Comment: @MartyMcVry, Exactly, the timer gets whatever is in mysql database and whats on mysql database for `$end_date` is `September 22 2013 23:30:00 GMT` which is 4 days 5 hours 50 minutes and a few seconds from today's date. but the countdown timer is showing `34d 06:21:48` which is way off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JavaScript `Date` object is constructed as follows:

```
Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
```

That means you probably should be doing something along these lines:

```
$end_date = date("Y, n, j, G, i, s", strtotime($row["end_date"]));
```

Sources:

- [JavaScript Date-object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)
- [PHP date-function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

**EDIT:**

In addition, I seem to have found the problem in the [jQuery Countdown](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) manual:

> A note on Date - the JavaScript Date constructor expects the year,
>   month, and day as parameters. However, the month ranges from 0 to 11.
>   To make explicit what date is intended (does a month of 3 mean March
>   or April?) I specify the month from 1 to 12 and manually subtract the
>   1. Thus the following denotes 25 December, 2010.

So, you'd have to split the string, substract 1 from the month and rebuild...

```
$tmp_date = explode(', ', $end_date);
$tmp_date[1] = $tmp_date[1] - 1;
$end_date = implode(', ', $tmp_date);
```

Link to [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3naf7/)

Comment: even with that formatting i still get `0 hours, 0 minutes, 0 seconds`.

Comment: wow, Bang on mate, so close but the hour is 1 hour behind. it should be 5 hours and it is showing 4 instead.

Comment: I'm starting to think it's a timezone issue... If possible, let the SQL-query output the `DateTime` in your own timezone.

Comment: I already have this on the top of the page: `<?php date_default_timezone_set('GMT'); ?>`

Comment: Yeah, but PHP and the SQL database are two seperate things... I've had several issues myself regarding times/timezones in some of the applications I've made. - Don't know what timezone you're in, but I'd suggest: `SELECT [...] CONVERT_TZ(end_date,'GMT','Europe/Brussels') AS end_date [...]` or something along those lines. `Europe/Brussels` might not be the right timezone for you.

Comment: I am based in the UK. i will mess around with your suggestion. I appreciate your help mate.