# How to control a function (countdown timer) on a different computer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, timer, window.open

I have a programming problem which I don't know how to handle in order to make what I want :)

I want to create a web-based software for my "real-life" escape the room business with the main functionality being the countdown timers in each of the two rooms (games). I have 3 computers with separate monitors in LAN network:

- A (server / control panel),
- B (room 1),
- C (room 2).

What I want to achieve is to be able to start the countdown timer from the server on computer B in a way, that when I open a specific url on this computer using e.g. remote desktop, the counter will be already running.
Right now I have:

- index.html file as the "Control panel",
- room1.html with counter for room 1 (computer B)
- room2.html with counter for room 2 (computer C).

Currently I have the basic functionality written in jQuery/Javascript using the jQuery Timer and window.open() function. Index.html has the Start/Stop/Reset buttons for controlling the timers in each room. However, it works only when I open the index.html page on the computer B or C and open the room1.html/room2.html page directly from it. I want to be able to open index.html on server, start the timer in room 1 and then when I log in to computer B, enter the room1.html URL in the browser and the timer will be already running. Same with stopping and resetting.

How can I achieve that? Is jQuery/Javascript enough? If so, how to do that? If not, how can I write that? With the use of PHP maybe?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You are going to need some sort of server side language such as php to achieve this .  You could try setting the timer in a database and then poll that timer on your client machines whilst the server updates the variable using ajax

Comment: Thanks! Based on what you wrote I now know what to look for and already found few questions regarding this problem, ie. how to use  MySQL together with PHP and jQuery timer to achieve this, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18876270/using-jquery-countdown-timer-with-mysql-datetime

Comment: Glad I could help - sorry I didn't have time to write a full answer been to busy with work. Just saw your question as I was skimming through :). Good luck!